# Как правильно оформить это предложение, в конце которого слеш есть-таки?

Tags: пунктуация, точка

Как правильно оформить это предложение, в конце которого слеш есть-таки?

> Я говорил сам с собой/собою.

> Я говорил сам с собой./собою.

А это?

> Кот пропал навеки / на века.

> Кот пропал навеки. / на века.

Comment: Что-то вы часто клавиатурные ошибки допускаете. Вы же имели в виду 'пропал'? У вас написано «провал». В общем, изменил вопрос на 2 буквы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Точка только в конце предложения.

`Я говорил сам с собой/собою.`

`Кот пропал навеки / на века.`

Точка не относится к «междуслешным» словам. Она относится ко всему предложению, завершает предложение полностью. Поэтому нельзя ее «склеивать» с предшествующим словом, к которому она не относится.

Только сокращающая точка не завершает предложение (завершающая опускается) и относится к конкретному слову, напр.:

`... и т. д. / т. п.`